# iOS7: CTLine does not honor NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName

Tags: ios7, core-text, textkit

In iOS7, using `NSLayoutManager` with an `NSTextStorage` with ranges that have `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` set with a positive or negative offset (for subscript and superscript) works - the resulting ranges are currently rendered with a vertical offset.

However, using the lower level Core Text API `CTTypesetterCreateLine` on the same `NSTextStorage` produces a `CTLine` that renders all ranges with no vertical offset.

Since TextKit was introduced in iOS7, my concern is that this attribute may only work via the higher level `NSLayoutManager` but not via `CTTypesetter`.

Is there a way to get vertical baseline offsets to work on iOS7 using `CTTypesetter`?